# Packages options not recognized

Tags: installing, texlive, linux, package-options

I installed TeX Live and I have a document containing this line:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

The document used to compile years ago, but now it does not seem to find `utf8x`.

What I did to install TeX Live with the network installer:

```
$ perl install install-pl
$ sudo tlmgr install latex latex-bin
```

Am I forgetting to install additionnal stuff?

**SOLVED**

Searching on [ctan.org](http://ctan.org/), I found that `utf8x.def` is in the `ucs` package, which means that I need to install it: `sudo tlmgr install ucs`. It solved my problem, but can someone confirm that it is the "standard" way to get this file? And for `utf8.def`, is it included in the `latex` package?

Comment: I removed the part with `babel` in my question, as I forgot to install the package for my language : `sudo tlmgr install babel-<language>`. `kpsewhich inputenc` returns nothing

Comment: Please provide us with a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) then that demonstrates the problem.  And add `\listfiles` to the preamble and add the very end of the `.log`, which should list where pdfTeX is (not) finding the files.

Comment: Yes you need the ucs package for that, please make an _answer_ rather than put the answer in the question (you can accept your own answer)

Answer (score 3):

I confirm to myself that `ucs` is the right package to install to get `utf8x.def` and `utf8.def` is included in the `latex` package. You can run `tlmgr info --list latex` to see `utf8.def`.